# How to create a Gird of images in android (like the attached screenshot)

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I want to to create a grid of images like this :

[image]

What I am asking about is how to make the images appear suitably, without being stretched or having a blink spaces. I just what the images (in different sizes) to fit the available spaces. ..

how ? and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).CENTER_CROP. CENTER_CROP ensures that every image will fit both the height and width of the allocated space with no gap. You can add to your xml via:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```